# Text size to match font size in inline fraction

Tags: fontsize, fractions

Suppose I type `$\frac{\text{foo}}{2}$` to produce a fraction with the text "foo" in the numerator. The "foo" text is smaller than the body text of the document if the math is inline.

Now I would like to type "bar" in plain text and have it be the same font size as the "foo" in the fraction. Is there a way to achieve this that works independently of the font packacge being used?

Four `fouriernc`, `\small{bar}` and `\footnotesize{bar}` look too big. `\scriptsize` looks too small.

---

To be clearer about my specific application, here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgfplots,fouriernc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=left,clip=false]
    \addplot{x} node [right] {$\frac{\text{foo}}{2}$};
    \addplot{x/2} node [right] {\scriptsize foo};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following plot. Note that the text in the labels  appears to be different in size.

[image]

To confirm this, I check the size of the two labels in photoshop:

[image]

---

**Update:** I realise that this indeed works in computer modern, but not for fouriernc, which is the font I am using. I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: Maybe `\scriptsize`?

Comment: Try `$\scriptstyle\text{bar}$` or  `$\scriptstyle\mathrm{bar}$`?

Comment: Thanks. I think `\scriptsize` is too small.

Comment: Actually you just have to use `\scriptsize bar`. I've measured (precision: 0.1 pt). Unless you don't use a standard font (Computer Modern or Latin Modern). B.t.w. `\scriptsize` is not used in the same context as `\scriptstyle`.

Comment: @Ubiquitous, can you give full MWE? `\scriptsize` matches exactly for me. Note it should be `{\scriptsize bar}` not `\scriptsize{bar}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\scriptsize` for both and `\dfrac`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,pgfplots,fouriernc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=left,clip=false]
    \addplot{x} node [right] {\scriptsize$\dfrac{\text{foo}}{2}$};
    \addplot{x/2} node [right] {\scriptsize foo};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here are the two words side by side

[image]
[image]

[image]